# Python argparse treatment of multiple but identical flags

Tags: python

All,

I want to create an argument parser that would allow multiple specification of the same command-line option (think of the `-e` flag of grep: you can specify multiple regexps). Here is my test code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="...my description...")
parser.add_argument("file", nargs="*",
                    help="email file(s) to process")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",
                    nargs=1, dest="input_list",
                    help="a text file containing filenames to process")
argp = parser.parse_args(args)
```

When `args` contains multiple `-i` option, for example: `['-i', 'file1', '-i', 'file2', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']`, I only got `'file2'` in the resulting namespace (`argp.input_list`).

Does argparse accommodate the case where `input_list` destination variable above can contain more than one values?

Wirawan

Answer (score 1):

`action='append'` is probably what you want, i.e:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="...my description...")
parser.add_argument("file", nargs="*",
                    help="email file(s) to process")
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",
                    dest="input_list", action='append',
                    help="a text file containing filenames to process")
argp = parser.parse_args(['-i', 'file1', '-i', 'file2', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
```

gives me:

```
Namespace(file=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], input_list=['file1', 'file2'])
```